# Is the black and white theme for QR Codes a standard?

Tags: java, android, ios, standards, qr-code

I'm developing a QR Code generator and would like to understand if it is okay to have a different color combination for the QRC image other than the black and white?

Will it cause any difference in the amount of data that can be stored or in the error correction levels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No hard and fast rules - you can have a QR code in other colours, provided the contrast between dark and light is sufficient to be interpreted. No difference in the amount of data that can be stored or any error correction possibility, just in the ability to separate dark from light in order to decode.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use other colors. But black/white provides the best contrast and so you receive best results.

Answer (score 3):

A normal QR-Code-App (like Zxing) is converting the image into a greyscale image before scanning it for QR-Codes.
So you can use any color you want, just make sure the contrast between your colors is as strong as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use colors (see for instance [the wikipedia article for QR Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Error_correction)), you may even round corners and do other [artistic stuff with your QR code](http://archive.is/20120710/http://mashable.com/2011/04/18/qr-code-design-tips/).

You can store the same amount of data, but I suspect black and white gives you a bit better chance of working (as it gives the best contrast).